# Is there a JGraph alternative for Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, graph, modeling

Which library can I use to develop an application for visual modeling with graphs?
Is there a library for Python like [JGraph](https://www.jgraph.com/) for Java?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is a powerful tool to make nice graphs and you have a python wrapper called  [PygraphViz](http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz/) that should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from JGraph, but [gnuplot](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/) has a Python wrapper.

Comment: Gnuplot is a plotting library, but I want to develop a visual designer with Drag and Drop features.

Comment: Ah, then Mermoz answered your question.